Thermogravimetric analysis
I have conducted a TGA analysis of polyurethane foam and defined the steps of degradation as follows. I have replotted the graph using Origin and marked the degradation steps. I do
have the first derivative data points as well.Since the steps of degradation are not pronounced, I am not exactly sure about the steps I have defined. I know that the major degradation step occurs due to the breakage of urethane bonds. Since I don't see a smaller mass loss before it, I assume the sample has no surface-bound water. I need to know if there is any better way of analyzing the data. Any and all feedback will be appreciated.


Is time not a factor?
